# Rails route works properly in development but fails on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm new to both Ruby and Rails and I've inherited an existing company website that I've been modifying to hit a new job tracking site.  Everything works great in development, but when I deploy to our staging server, two of my job routes begin having problems.

Before I describe in more detail, I'm using the following versions on an AWS Linux server:

- Ruby 1.9.3-p392
- Rails 3.2.13
- Passenger 4.0.37
- Apache 2.2.26

I have two routes that are causing problems: viewing a job posting and applying for the job.  Sometimes the job posting shows up at both URLs and sometimes the job application shows up for both URLs, I think it ends up displaying whichever page loaded first.

The lines in routes.rb related to the jobs_controller are (comments added to explain URLs):

```
# Submits a general application to the company
get '/careers/apply', controller: :jobs, action: :apply, as: :apply

# Applies to a particular position
get '/career/:ref_number/apply', controller: :jobs, action: :apply, as: :apply_job

# Displays details for a particular job opening
get '/career/:ref_number', controller: :jobs, action: :show, as: :job

# Searches available job openings
get '/careers/search', controller: :jobs, action: :search, as: :job
```

I've tried reordering routes in the file, changing URLs so they don't overlap and changing HTTP methods and nothing has worked.

jobs_controller.rb:

```
require 'pagination'
require 'related'
require 'job_selector'

class JobsController < ApplicationController
  include Website::Pagination

  before_filter :set_page_or_redirect, only: :index
  skip_authorization_check

  def index
    @jobs = Job.with_tag_associations.page(@page)
  end

  def show

    @job = Job.find_by_ref_number(params[:ref_number])
    related_job_finder = Website::Related.new(@job)
    @related_jobs = {
      tags: related_job_finder.related(Job, :tags).limit(5).to_a,
      categories: related_job_finder.related(Job, :categories).limit(5).to_a,
    }
    @featured_jobs = Website::JobSelector.random_featured_jobs(2)
  end

  def search
    @location = params[:location]
    @query = params[:query]

    @search = Job.solr_search(@query, params.slice(:location, :category, :page))

    @jobs = @search.results
  end

  def apply
    if !params[:ref_number].nil?
      @job = Job.find_by_ref_number(params[:ref_number])
      related_job_finder = Website::Related.new(@job)
      @related_jobs = {
          tags: related_job_finder.related(Job, :tags).limit(5).to_a,
          categories: related_job_finder.related(Job, :categories).limit(5).to_a,
      }
    else
      @job = Job.new(ref_number: -1,
                     title: 'General Application')
      @related_jobs = {
          tags: [],
          categories: []
      }
    end
    @featured_jobs = Website::JobSelector.random_featured_jobs(2)
  end
end
```

My staging.log file shows the following when I viewed a job requisition, then clicked the Apply button to view the application page.  According to the logs, the correct controller methods are called and the correct views/* components are loaded for each page, but - in this instance - both URLs displayed the job details and I couldn't get to the job application.

View Job Page (`GET /career/70779`)

```
Started GET "/career/70779" for 173.66.87.200 at 2014-02-27 04:04:42 +0000
Processing by JobsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"ref_number"=>"70779"}
  Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE `jobs`.`ref_number` = 70779 LIMIT 1
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
  Job Load (1.5ms)  SELECT jobs.*, COUNT(tags.id) AS count FROM jobs, tags, taggings WHERE (jobs.id != 261 AND jobs.id = taggings.taggable_id AND taggings.taggable_type = 'Job' AND taggings.tag_id = tags.id AND tags.name IN (NULL)) GROUP BY jobs.id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'categories' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT jobs.*, COUNT(tags.id) AS count FROM jobs, tags, taggings WHERE (jobs.id != 261 AND jobs.id = taggings.taggable_id AND taggings.taggable_type = 'Job' AND taggings.tag_id = tags.id AND tags.name IN (NULL)) GROUP BY jobs.id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
   (24.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'primary_category')
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'primary_category') LIMIT 1
Read fragment views/jobs/261-20140226035339 (0.2ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'primary_category')
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'primary_category') LIMIT 1
  Rendered shared/_category_label.html.erb (8.5ms)
  Rendered shared/share_links/_twitter.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/share_links/_facebook.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/share_links/_google_plus.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/share_links/_linkedin.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered jobs/_share_links.html.erb (29.6ms)
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'tags')
  Rendered shared/_tags.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered jobs/_apply_button.html.erb (1.0ms)
Read fragment views/jobs/261-20140226035339/join-us (0.1ms)
  Job Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE `jobs`.`is_featured` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
Read fragment views/jobs/263-20140226190437/sidebar (0.1ms)
Write fragment views/jobs/263-20140226190437/sidebar (4.1ms)
Read fragment views/jobs/262-20140226164039/sidebar (0.1ms)
Write fragment views/jobs/262-20140226164039/sidebar (27.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_show_sidebar.html.erb (178.1ms)
Write fragment views/jobs/261-20140226035339/join-us (2.8ms)
  Rendered jobs/_side_bar.html.erb (184.0ms)
Write fragment views/jobs/261-20140226035339 (2.6ms)
  Rendered jobs/show.html.erb within layouts/application (386.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (3.4ms)
Read fragment views/navigation (0.1ms)
Write fragment views/navigation (2.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_context_nav.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (24.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_javascripts.html.erb (4.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (31.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1860ms (Views: 683.4ms | ActiveRecord: 34.6ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

Apply for Job Page (`GET /career/70779/apply`)

```
Started GET "/career/70779/apply" for 173.66.87.200 at 2014-02-27 04:04:56 +0000
Processing by JobsController#apply as HTML
  Parameters: {"ref_number"=>"70779"}
  Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs` WHERE `jobs`.`ref_number` = 70779 LIMIT 1
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'tags' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
  Job Load (1.0ms)  SELECT jobs.*, COUNT(tags.id) AS count FROM jobs, tags, taggings WHERE (jobs.id != 261 AND jobs.id = taggings.taggable_id AND taggings.taggable_type = 'Job' AND taggings.tag_id = tags.id AND tags.name IN (NULL)) GROUP BY jobs.id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'categories' AND taggings.tagger_id IS NULL)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT jobs.*, COUNT(tags.id) AS count FROM jobs, tags, taggings WHERE (jobs.id != 261 AND jobs.id = taggings.taggable_id AND taggings.taggable_type = 'Job' AND taggings.tag_id = tags.id AND tags.name IN (NULL)) GROUP BY jobs.id ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'primary_category')
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 261 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Job' AND (taggings.context = 'primary_category') LIMIT 1
Read fragment views/jobs/261-20140226035339 (0.4ms)
  Rendered jobs/apply.html.erb within layouts/application (6.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (130.7ms)
Read fragment views/navigation (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_context_nav.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_javascripts.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (3.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 144.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.1ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

My deployment script does the following:

```
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake db:migrate
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake assets:precompile
touch tmp/restart.txt
RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

config/environments/staging.rb:

```
NewWebsite::Application.configure do
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Do fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Turn on memory caching (tried this after seeing some SO answers; didn't make a difference)
  config.cache_store = :memory_store

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
end
```

One last detail.  I was able to duplicate the problem locally while running `RAILS_ENV=staging rails s` after precompiling the assets so I don't think its related to Apache/Passenger vs local execution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked if the schema is updated on the staging server?

Comment: @rav: yes, it is updated (assuming you are referring to db/schema.rb)

Comment: @Philip7899: nope, on a Mac, tested with Firefox, Safari and Chrome so I'm pretty sure its a server-side issue and not client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just learned a very long lesson about Rails fragment caching!

I was running into this problem because I had copied the `show.html.erb` file responsible for displaying job details and edited it to make the `apply.html.erb` file that displayed the IFRAME with the actual application.  Not realizing what it was doing, I left the following line in the `apply.html.erb` file:

```
<% cache @job do %>
```

I've now realized that turns on Rails fragment caching, which explains all of my problems:

- Caching was disabled in `development` and enabled in `staging` and `production` which is why this problem never showed up locally.
- Since the `<% cache @job do %>` block was identical in both fragments, it explains why I saw the content from whichever page I hit first for any given job in both URLs.

The solution:

Removed the `cache` block from the application fragment since it is doing negligible processing.  Rails now generates that page appropriately every time it is loaded while still caching the job details display page.